# encrypting c source files

Tags: c, encryption, dll

I´m searching for a way to encrypt my C source files. That way, I can handle it to some project partners. I don´t want them to see my code but I want them to use the functions I implemented so they can flash it on a microcontroller.

Is it even possible to encrypt a source file so J-Link can flash it?
I got told to look up for DLL but I don´t know if a DLL would help in this situation.

For software, I use Dave v4 as IDE and FreeRTOS as firmware. For Hardware I use a XMC4700 Relax Kit.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Before posting, please visit the [help] and read [ask] to understand the guidelines for what is on-topic here.

Comment: Yes, learning about DLL/shared libraries will help. Go do that.

Comment: Why source?  Why not simply provide pre-compiled libraries to be used?  Gut feel, if you can arrange for the compiler to decrypt the source, then the customer can arrange to capture the source in its decrypted state.

Answer (score 1):

**DLLs won't help,**

because your platform (presumably) lacks a dynamic loader. It might be possible to create one, but it doesn't worth the trouble, because you can just

**ship the object files.**

For that to work, you need a copy of your partner's compiler. Compile your sources exactly as they'd do it (with the same compiler options), and ship the resulting object files along with the headers needed to use it.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You want to protect your intellectual property, and you think you can use encryption to do that. You asked about encryption, when you should have asked about protecting your intellectual property.

Encryption isn't very useful for protecting intellectual property. If your clients machine can decrypt the code to run it then your client can decrypt the code. If your client can't decrypt the code the client can't run it. Either way, problems are introduced...

The solution to your problem is the legal system. Use that to protect your intellectual property, instead.

Comment: "Encryption isn't very useful for protecting intellectual property" well, it depends; in general encryption done right is solid, of course in a case like this (encryption, but shipping the key in some oblique manner) it's essentially security by obscurity, which however does have some value. In particular, it clearly states that the source is not to be looked at (it removes plausible deniability), and discourages the "casual" attacker, which is often the only kind of adversary you have to deal with. Also, it's not an either-or, you can do both (actually, one reinforces the other).

Comment: That being said, I wouldn't ever buy a library without having the sources to look at - bugs do happen and I want to be able to understand what's going on (at the very least, to see if the problem is on my side or on their side).

Comment: I'd love to see that in court... "Yes, your honour, we gave the client the key and the safe full of sekritz, but the safe clearly states that the contents aren't to be inspected."